# How to fetch names from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I want output as:

> for checkBasket(amazonBasket, amazonBasket.floss) => floss is in your
> basket

```
amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for (item in basket) {
    if (item.name === lookingFor.name) {
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`
    }
  }
  return 'that does not exist in your basket'
}
```

Comment: If you just pass `100` into the function, you won’t be able to find anything by name…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for in loop in javascript already iterates through the object keys. In fact, the `item` variable is the item name, not the item value.

```js
amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for (item in basket) {
    if (item === lookingFor) {
      // if you want the quantity, simple retrieve it like normal: basket[item]
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`
    }
  }
  return 'that does not exist in your basket'
}

console.log(checkBasket(amazonBasket, "floss"))
console.log(checkBasket(amazonBasket, "something_else"))
```

Comment: Of course… `return lookingFor in basket`…